# How to create unique ID to join SQL tables by combing the columns 1 and 2?

Tags: sql

Looking to join two tables in SQL. Since there is no unique ID to join on I'm left clueless. Should I insert a column and concatenate to create a unique ID? Learning everything I can get my hands on and this would be a big help.

Below are the tables in two different files. I want to join the two and put the Qty in table 2 next to the Qty in Table 1.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "unique ID"?  There may not be a column labeled "ID", but it appears that you have other columns which could uniquely identify the rows of data.  SQL joins are not limited to only ID columns, but you could join on `Plant` and `Part #` for instance.

Comment: Please only tag the database you're actually using, not multiple different ones

Comment: I want to join on the Plant and Part # to get the corresponding value. I pull the data into excel then concatenate to make a unique string to vlookup against to pull the quantity. I can join on plant but it wont be by specific part. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @CaptianBoredASF  Notice that Shawn removed the multiple database tags.  He failed to explain that you should edit the question and re-add only the database that you are using.

Comment: From your sample data you clearly have a unique field Plant and you can use that column to join the tables. Does that column have duplicate data?

Comment: You can have a composite key with both `Plant` and `Part#` and join using both. i think this will solve your problem.

Comment: According to your tables there are two unique keys like plant and part# ,so you can use one of them

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and also be sure to tag the correct RDMS..

Answer (score -1):

You should [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) on the plant and part.

```
select t1.plant, t1.part, t1.qty, t2.qty
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.plant = t2.plant and t1.part = t2.part
```

As for table design, you should declare the combination of plant and part unique to ensure it can work as a key. How you do this depends on your database. [Here's how you do it in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/indexes-unique.html).

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table1_plant_part_key ON table1 (plant, part);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table2_plant_part_key ON table2 (plant, part);
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Indexes are not part of the SQL standard. Implementations have done a good job of harmonizing index syntax, but I don't know which their using.

Comment: . .You are right. Now that you mention it, I'm pretty sure it was not in the 1992 standard (the last one I memorized). I thought it was an "optional" functionality buried in there somewhere, because the syntax is so similar among databases.  Usually vendors are not so consistent.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, it's weird. My hypothesis is it's considered an implementation issue (ie. does not affect the result of a query), which is absurd, and it's such an old feature that the syntax has, mostly, settled down.

Comment: . . I fully understand why.  Many very powerful databases do not need indexes (BigQuery, Redshift, Hive, for example) because they have different execution models.  I just figured that the syntax was in the standard as an option, for those products that do support them -- I think `begin transaction` is in there, for instance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff A transaction will affect the result of the query. It would be nice if there was an optional standard for indexes and the like.